# Active record is not returning specific columns when using model.find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using active record for Job model that I've a table for it in postgres database.

When calling Job.all it should return all rows in jobs table with all its columns.

There is around 60 columns for jobs table, I'm getting back a json array with most of the columns except a column named start_date.

Is there a config I'm missing or this specific name can't be returned?

```rb
class Api::V1::JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
    render json: @jobs
  end

end
```

Comment: are you sure start_date is in the schema and not a virtual attribute or method? Does `Job.new.attributes.key?("start_date")` return true?

Comment: Job.new.attributes.key?("start_date") returned true

Comment: Do you have custom `as_json` method or do you write custom data using `serializer`? it's weird :)

Comment: Thanks @quyetdc indeed `start_date` is missing from `JobSerializer`

Comment: Try `puts @jobs.as_json` to see if it's an issue with JSON formatting versus `render`. Or even without the json `puts @jobs.first.attributes`

Comment: @AK paste the code of the model, so we can have more data about your problem

Comment: Thanks all it was `JobSerializer` issue, `start_date` was missing so I add it and it worked as expected.

Comment: @quyetdc please post your comment as an answer so I can mark question solved.

Comment: Thanks @AK. I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have `serializer` or custom `as_json` method for your model and you lack the field